# Splitting up html code tags and content

Tags: php, regex, arrays, split, preg-split

Does anyone with more knowledge than me about regular expressions know how to split up html code so that all tags and all words are seperated ie.

```
<p>Some content <a href="www.test.com">A link</a></p>
```

Is seperated like this:

```
array = { [0]=>"<p>",
          [1]=>"Some",
          [2]=>"content",
          [3]=>"<a href='www.test.com'>,
          [4]=>"A",
          [5]=>"Link",
          [6]=>"</a>",
          [7]=>"</p>"
```

I've been using preg_split so far and have either successfully managed to split the string by whitespace or split by tags - but then all the content is in one array element when I eed this to be split to.

Anyone help me out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

preg_split shouldn't be used in that case. Try preg_match_all:

```
$text = '<p>Some content <a href="www.test.com">A link</a></p>';
preg_match_all('/<[^>]++>|[^<>\s]++/', $text, $tokens);
print_r($tokens);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <p>
            [1] => Some
            [2] => content
            [3] => <a href="www.test.com">
            [4] => A
            [5] => link
            [6] => </a>
            [7] => </p>
        )

)
```

I assume you forgot to include the `'A'` in `'A link'` in your example.

Realize that when your HTML contains < or >'s not meant as the start or end of tags, regex will mess things up badly! (hence the warnings)

Comment: @Bart If you know it isn't the right way, perhaps post the right way when you have time.

Comment: @mickmackusa I never said it was wrong or right. Only about the `preg_split`, which I recommended to use `preg_match_all` for. I only warned that when the HTML is malformed, the solution would break, which are what the warnings from the other SO users are about (in whose's answers there are alternatives to my proposal).

Answer (score 2):

You could check out [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Or look at the [DOM parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) in PHP

Comment: Thanks for this! However I need to easily loop through each element - which is why I was going for a simple array. As far as I can tell there's not an easy way to do this with Dom Parser....?

Comment: I don't have rep enough to comment below, but re: helen's mention of "splitting into 3 evenish chunks while keeping tags closed...". I'd ask whether you're talking about full pages or snippets of html? Because of course you've got the &lt;body&gt; tag/block which covers all the content, and there could be div tags that more or less enclose the entire body.

Comment: This kind of a vague hint would be better positioned as a comment under the question because it doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Simple HTML Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) a try. HTML is too irregular for regular expressions.

Comment: This kind of a vague hint would be better positioned as a comment under the question because it doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I currently use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) in several applications and find it to be an excellent tool, even when compared against other HTML parsers written in other languages.

Why exactly are you splitting up HTML into the string of tokens you described? Is not a tree-like structure of DOM elements a better approach for your specific application?

Comment: No - the reason I'm splitting it up so much is because I need to split some html code into 3 evenish chunks - whilst making sure all tags are closed at the point of splitting. So my plan is to loop through word by word - storing what tags are open whilst I go. I'm open to suggestions on better ways of doing this

Comment: Actually - I'm going to approach this in a much cleaner way. Splitting things by <p> tags. Still be in chunks of 3 or 2 but very uneven - not perfect but also avoids any nasty accidents. Thanks for everyones reply!

Comment: Well, Simple HTML DOM Parser could be used to return objects that represent every <p> tag, giving you the option of inspecting their contents as needed.

The following example loads HTML stored in $string into a simple_html_dom object, extracts all <p> tags from within and then prints the contents of each <p> tag.

$html = str_get_html($string);

$p_tags = $html->find('p');

foreach ($p_tags as $p_tag) {
    echo $p_tag->innertext;
}

Comment: This answer is a vague hint followed by questions to the OP.  All of which would be better positioned as comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Bart about the recommendation of `preg_match_all()` over `preg_split()`.

The task is literally to "split" the whole string on a variety of delimiters.  I, first, recommend the stability of using a dom parser over regex, but if you don't require that level of stability because your input html is relatively predictable/simplistic, then regex can be used as a cheaper, more concise alternative.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/isVsi))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p>Some content <a href="www.test.com">A link</a></p>
HTML;

var_export(preg_split('~\s+|(<[^>]+>)~', $html, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<p>',
  1 => 'Some',
  2 => 'content',
  3 => '<a href="www.test.com">',
  4 => 'A',
  5 => 'link',
  6 => '</a>',
  7 => '</p>',
)
```

My pattern splits on one or more whitespace characters or on a (weak interpretation of a) html tag.  The whitespaces are merely discarded.  The tags are retained in the output.

Beyond logical semantics, `preg_split()` has the additional benefit of producing a less bloated and therefore more direct output.  `preg_split()` provides a one dimensional array and `preg_match_all()` provides a multidimensional array.

Finally, `preg_split()` cannot "fail" like `preg_match_all()` might.  Imagine the unlikely fringe case where the input string doesn't contain any spaces or tags. `preg_split()` will return the whole input string as a single element array (useful and consistent with more common input strings). `preg_match_all()` will generate an empty array (not very useful).